# Using pipes/proxies with concurrent MVars

Tags: haskell

In the `Control.Proxy` tutorial for the `pipes-3.1.0` package, the author provides this function:

```
cache :: (Proxy p, Ord key) => key -> p key val key val IO r
cache = runIdentityK (loop M.empty) where
    loop _map key = case M.lookup key _map of
        Nothing -> do
            val  <- request key
            key2 <- respond val
            loop (M.insert key val _map) key2
        Just val -> do
            lift $ putStrLn "Used cache!"
            key2 <- respond val
            loop _map key2
```

Because I'd like to have a concurrent application caching requests, I have the following data type

`newtype Cache k v = Cache (MVar (M.Map k v))`

and now I want a new `cache` function with the signature

```
cache :: (Proxy p, Ord k) => Cache k v -> k -> p k v k v IO r
cache (Cache c) k = readMVar c >>= \m -> runIdentityK $ loop m k
    where loop m key = case M.lookup key m of
            Nothing -> do
                val <- request key
                respond val >>= loop (M.insert key val m)
            Just val -> respond val >>= loop m
```

however, this fails to typecheck since `readMVar` is in the `IO` monad, and `runIdentityK` is in the `Proxy p => p k v k v IO r` monad. Surely I can lift `readMVar` into this proxy monad since it's a transformer over `IO`, but I cant find the right combinator.

Comment: Petr's version is also much safer from deadlock compared to Chris Dueck's!  Imagine that `request key` also tries to access the same Cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was a simple `lift`. I had thought to use it before but apparently hadn't tried hard enough. Here is a rough, type-checking version of my desired `cache`

```
cache = runIdentityK . loop
    where loop (Cache c) key = lift (takeMVar c) >>= \m -> case M.lookup key m of
            Nothing -> do
                val <- request key
                lift . putMVar c $ M.insert key val m
                respond val >>= loop (Cache c)
            Just val -> do
               lift $ putMVar c m 
               respond val >>= loop (Cache c)
```

Comment: This looks quite unsafe when there are exceptions.  The take & put should be replaced by withMVar.

Comment: withMVar won't work since he needs to do pipe actions in between acquisition and release, but he can use bracket from pipes-safe to safely acquire and release it in the face of exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

It's just as simple as adding `lift`. However, it seems that your implementation doesn't do what you intended. You read your `MVar` only once at the start and then never use it again, just pass the updated map around in the loop. If different threads should see changes through the `MVar`, you have to update it as well. A suggestion (compiles, but I haven't tested how it works):

```
cache :: (Proxy p, Ord k) => Cache k v -> k -> p k v k v IO r
cache (Cache c) k = runIdentityK loop k
    where 
      loop key = do
        m <- lift (readMVar c)
        case M.lookup key m of
            Nothing -> do
                val <- request key
                lift $ modifyMVar_ c (return . M.insert key val)
                respond val >>= loop
            Just val -> respond val >>= loop
```

Comment: Chris' version is probably better as it avoids a possible race condition by using `takeMVar`/`putMVar` (although for a cache it probably isn't an issue).

Comment: Note about Petr's comment: the race condition is two threads call `readMVar` then the two threads call `modifyMVar`.  If done with the same `key` then the `request` is made twice instead of once.  The two inserts should be of the same `val` so the correctness will not be harmed.